# monotonicity of power function

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power

Following is Example 4.1.4 from Bickel and Doksum's mathematical statistics book. Given an iid sample $X_1, ..., X_n$. each $X_i$ has a Bernoulli distribution with unknown parameter $\theta$.

Given a constant $\theta_0$, we want to test $H: \theta=\theta_0$ versus $K: \theta >\theta_0$.

The test statistic is $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and the testing procedure $I_{S_n \geq k}$.

If $\theta_0 =0.3$ and $n=10$ and $k=6$, the power function of $\theta$ is a increasing function. See Figure 4.1.1.

My question is to go beyond this example to more general case. In a general hypothesis testing task or some more general one than the example, is there some property of the power function that is similar to or generalizes monotonicity of the power function in the example?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the hypothesis test. There do exist tests with nonmonotonic power functions.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks! What are some cases, when the power function is monotonic?

Comment: Look up "monotone likelihood ratio" families; *e.g.,* in [this presentation](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~shao/stat710/stat710-21.pdf).